# Хороший тон в использовании членов класса при вызове методов класса

Tags: c++, классы, методы, параметры, инкапсуляция

Подскажите как лучше (правильнее/логичнее/красивее и т.д.) реализовывать следующий функционал. Есть класс `CMyFunctional`, с методами:

```
CMyFunctional::init(...)
CMyFunctional::start()
```

В методе `init` передаются определённые параметры, которые обрабатываются и сохраняются как члены класса `m_params`, а в методе `start` вызываются в том числе приватные методы класса, например `CMyFunctional::calc`, которые используют сохранённые ранее параметры.

**Так вот вопрос:**

Стоит ли передавать параметры в метод `calc` как внешний параметр или все таки лучше и логичнее, чтобы метод `calc` использовал параметры, сохранённые как член класса `m_params`?

Т.е. вопрос в том, стоит или нет практиковать такой вызов методов класса (пример написал сильно упрощённый, но суть вопроса он раскрывает)

```
class CMyFunctional
{
protected:
    int m_value;

protected:
    void calc(const int value);

public:
    void init(const int value) {
        m_value = value;
    }

    void start() {
        calc(m_value);
    }
};
```

Comment: А почему из `start` есть доступ к приватным членам `calc`?

Comment: Каковы отношнеия между классами `CMyFunctional` и `calc`? Какую задачу решает их взаимодействие?

Comment: @Cerbo ну в `start` запускаются потоки (параллельная обработка), в потоках вызываются приватные методы, которые используют данные, переданные объекту класса через `init`

вот я и мучаюсь вопросом (понятно, что и так и так все работать будет, но интересно как по науке) - можно и в явном виде все необходимые данные передать, а можно и в качестве параметра

Comment: @Cerbo: `calc` - это приватный метод класса  `CMyFunctional` (`CMyFunctional::calc`), а 'start' - публичный (`CMyFunctional::start`) - который и запускает всю обработку (многопотоковую и т.д.)

Comment: Если calc - метод того же самого класса CMyFunctional, то какой смысл передавать ему как параметры те данные, которые и так ему доступны?? ИМХО, бессмысленная трата времени и памяти.

Comment: @Zhihar Тогда исправте вопрос, сейчас написано что `calc` это класс.

Comment: вопрос непонятен. пожалуйста добавьте деталей и кода. Что за класс, что делают методы, т.к. судя по коментам там что-то порождает потоки и какой-то не то класс, не то метод calc что-то считает.

Comment: *"Стоит ли передавать параметры в метод calc как внешний параметр или все таки лучше и логичнее, чтобы метод calc использовал параметры, сохранённые как член класса m_params?"* - эти два варианта не являются альтернативами

Comment: по примеру. зачем вообще эти лишние методы и почему бы не сделать публичным сам calc?

Comment: Сам факт наличия метода `init` указывает на потенциальные проблемы с дизайном данного класса - почему эту бы функцию не возложить на конструктор?

Comment: Нет, не стоит передавать члены класса как параметры. Иначе может возникнуть путаница между полями класса, и параметрами. Так делают, когда метод по каким-то причинам нужно сделать статический.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Если  функции_члены класса, его друзья или производные классы часто
   используют один и тот же код, то тогда следует обернуть этот код в
   отдельную функцию(в вашем примере только один вызов этой
   функции...). Если эта функциональность нужна только для реализации
   этого класса и его производных классов, то тогда следует
   использовать ее как защищенный член.
2. Если вы создали нужную абстракцию и хорошо инкапсулировали данные, о
   которых не нужно знать пользовательям, то следует подумать и о
   сохранении инварианта, а для этого,  в первую очередь, конструктор
   класса должен инициализировать свои неинициализированные члены (что
   не наблюдается у вас).
3. Если вы инкапсулировали данные как защищенные члены, вы наверняка
   допускаете, что будут наследники, для реализации которых нужны эти
   члены.
4. Для того, чтобы определить как лучше написать, какие методы должны
   иметь каждый из классов(при этом избегать разбуханию кода класса), вы должны четко представлять какую задачу
   выполняет каждый класс в иерархии (может вам вообше лучше иметь
   абстрактный базовый класс с этими методами), и пока это знаете
   только вы, то, естественно, никто кроме вас не сможет дать полный ответ о хорошем тоне...